# When will Autodesk Forge support Geopackage and RDF?

Tags: autodesk-forge

At https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/ I can check the formats currently supported by Autodesk Forge. Are you working towards enabling expression of the datasets in Geopackage (see https://www.ogc.org/standards/geopackage) and RDF/Turtle (https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/ and https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/)?

Answer (score 0):

While there are a few exceptions (like the OBJ or FBX files that are very common for 3D data exchange), Forge is typically used with design formats used in architecture, engineering, construction, manufacturing, or media & entertainment. I don't know if the formats you mention fall into any of these categories, but if they do, I'd be happy to bring them up with the Forge team as a suggestion.

If the Geopackage or RDF files are meant to provide some additional context to other types of designs (like DWG drawings, for example), please note that you can load them yourself, and add their information into the DWG loaded in the viewer using the viewer's JavaScript API.